# Javascript iCal Parser Script ignore Tmezone

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make a script that I found on the internet to work with my ics file, so I can add it to my project.

The script works fine if I remove the timezone section from the ics file.
But because that file will be dynamically fetched from the internet I wont be able to edit it on the go.
So somehow I have to modify my code to skip or make use of that section.

The code is ([Source](https://github.com/thybag/JavaScript-Ical-Parser)):

```
/** 
 * Javascript ical Parser
 * Proof of concept method of reading icalendar (.ics) files with javascript.
 *
 * @author: Carl Saggs
 * @source: https://github.com/thybag/
 * @version: 0.2
 */
function ical_parser(feed_url, callback){
    //store of unproccesed data.
    this.raw_data = null;
    //Store of proccessed data.
    this.events = [];

    /**
     * loadFile
     * Using AJAX to load the requested .ics file, passing it to the callback when completed.
     * @param url URL of .ics file
     * @param callback Function to call on completion.
     */
    this.loadFile = function(url, callback){
        //Create request object
        try {xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest(): new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}  catch (e) { }
        //Grab file
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200)) {
                //On success, run callback.
                callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }

    /**
     * makeDate
     * Convert the dateformat used by ICalendar in to one more suitable for javascript.
     * @param String ical_date 
     * @return dt object, includes javascript Date + day name, hour/minutes/day/month/year etc.
     */
    this.makeDate = function(ical_date){
        //break date apart
        var dt =  {
            year: ical_date.substr(0,4),
            month: ical_date.substr(4,2),
            day: ical_date.substr(6,2),
            hour: ical_date.substr(9,2),
            minute: ical_date.substr(11,2)
        }
        //Create JS date (months start at 0 in JS - don't ask)
        dt.date = new Date(dt.year, (dt.month-1), dt.day, dt.hour, dt.minute);
        //Get the full name of the given day
        dt.dayname =["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"][dt.date.getDay()];
        return dt;
    }

    /**
     * parseICAL
     * Convert the ICAL format in to a number of javascript objects (Each representing a date)
     *
     * @param data Raw ICAL data
     */
    this.parseICAL = function(data){
        //Ensure cal is empty
        this.events = [];

        //Clean string and split the file so we can handle it (line by line)
        cal_array = data.replace(new RegExp( "\\r", "g" ), "").split("\n");     
        //Keep track of when we are activly parsing an event
        var in_event = false;
        //Use as a holder for the current event being proccessed.
        var cur_event = null;
        for(var i=0;i<cal_array.length;i++){
            ln = cal_array[i];
            //If we encounted a new Event, create a blank event object + set in event options.
            if(!in_event && ln == 'BEGIN:VEVENT'){
                in_event = true;
                cur_event = {};
            }
            //If we encounter end event, complete the object and add it to our events array then clear it for reuse.
            if(in_event && ln == 'END:VEVENT'){
                in_event = false;
                this.events.push(cur_event);
                cur_event = null;
            }
            //If we are in an event
            if(in_event){
                //Split the item based on the first ":"
                idx = ln.indexOf(':');
                //Apply trimming to values to reduce risks of badly formatted ical files.
                type = ln.substr(0,idx).replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');//Trim
                val = ln.substr(idx+1,ln.length-(idx+1)).replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');

                //If the type is a start date, proccess it and store details
                if(type.indexOf('DTSTART') != -1 ){
                    dt = this.makeDate(val);
                    val = dt.date;
                    //These are helpful for display
                    cur_event.start_time = dt.hour+':'+dt.minute;
                    cur_event.start_date = dt.day+'/'+dt.month+'/'+dt.year;
                    cur_event.day = dt.dayname;
                }
                //If the type is an end date, do the same as above
                if(type.indexOf('DTEND') != -1 ){
                    dt = this.makeDate(val);
                    val = dt.date;
                    //These are helpful for display
                    cur_event.end_time = dt.hour+':'+dt.minute;
                    cur_event.end_date = dt.day+'/'+dt.month+'/'+dt.year;
                    cur_event.day = dt.dayname;
                }
                //Convert timestamp
                if(type =='DTSTAMP') val = this.makeDate(val).date;

                //Add the value to our event object.
                cur_event[type] = val;
                //console.log(cur_event);
            }
        }
        //Run this to finish proccessing our Events.
        this.complete();
    }
    /**
     * complete
     * Sort all events in to a sensible order and run the original callback
     */
    this.complete = function(){
        //Sort the data so its in date order.
        this.events.sort(function(a,b){
            return a.DTSTART-b.DTSTART;
        });
        //Run callback method, if was defined. (return self)
        if(typeof callback == 'function') callback(this);
    }
    /**
     * getEvents
     * return all events found in the ical file.
     *
     * @return list of events objects
     */
    this.getEvents = function(){
        return this.events;
    }

    /**
     * getFutureEvents
     * return all events sheduled to take place after the current date.
     *
     * @return list of events objects
     */
    this.getFutureEvents = function(){
        var future_events = [], current_date = new Date();

        this.events.forEach(function(itm){
            //If the event starts after the current time, add it to the array to return.
            if(itm.DTSTART > current_date) future_events.push(itm);
            console.log(itm);
        });
        return future_events;
    }

    /**
     * load
     * load a new ICAL file.
     *
     * @param ical file url
     */
    this.load = function(ical_file){
        var tmp_this = this;
        this.raw_data = null;
        this.loadFile(ical_file, function(data){
            //if the file loads, store the data and invoke the parser
            tmp_this.raw_data = data;
            tmp_this.parseICAL(data);
        });
    }

    //Store this so we can use it in the callback from the load function.
    var tmp_this = this;
    //Store the feed url
    this.feed_url = feed_url;
    //Load the file
    this.load(this.feed_url);
}
```

I think the issue starts on the getFutureEvents, which compares the current date with the date on the file.

My file looks like:

```
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTSTAMP:20170217T034951Z
    DTSTART;TZID=Europe/London:20170330T090000
    DTEND;TZID=Europe/London:20170330T100000
    SUMMARY:Blah Blah Blah
    LOCATION:Blah 0.20
    DESCRIPTION:Week Number: 9\nBuilding: Blah\nRoom: 0.30\nUnit Ref: U
     87454/n
     Lecturer: Blah\,Blah
    LAST-MODIFIED:20170217T034950Z
    END:VEVENT
```

The sample ics file looks like:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:uid_1@test.com
DTSTAMP:20120120T130000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=Test:MAILTO:test@test.com
DTSTART:20120507T130000Z
DTEND:20120507T140000Z
SUMMARY:Intro to Witchcraft and wizardry
DESCRIPTION:A Description of this Event here
END:VEVENT
```

Comment: Could you tell me please how do you expect your file to be interpreted? I think that's everything to do, but I must know the final format you'd like receive. Especially your `DESCRIPTION` field raises my doubts. Is that one line of file or three?

Comment: What I really need to do as a 1st step is to somehow remove any possible timezones from the file. For example, some ical file have DTSTART;TZID=Europe/London:20170330T090000. But in order for the iCal Parser to read it, Timezone should not be included. So the line should be DTSTART:20170330T090000. ;TZID=Europe/London should be removed. I think here we gonna need a regex to delete everything between ; and :  (including the ;)

Comment: I dont really need the description. Just DTSART, DTEND, SUMMARY AND Location. The rest will be skipped by the iCal parser.

Comment: Could you tell sth about my answer? Does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited the `parseICAL` method and it seems to be sufficient for your needs now (but still not perfect). There're my changes:

```
this.parseICAL = function(data){
  /* ... */
  for(var i=0;i<cal_array.length;i++){
    ln = cal_array[i];
    ln = ln.trim(); // <-- here I'm trimming every line, because I noticed
                    // that spaces was causing some problems

    /* ... */
    if(in_event){
      idx = ln.indexOf(':');
      type = ln.substr(0,idx).replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
      val = ln.substr(idx+1,ln.length-(idx+1)).replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
      type = type.split(';')[0]; // <-- and here I am removing everything
                                 // after semicolon in types

      /* ... */
    }
  }
  this.complete();
}
```

I hope it'll be working now, it was working for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'll check it out tomorrow. It seems to be fine though. I'll get back to you soon Karol.

Comment: Thanks, Karol. It works as expected! I appreciate your time and effort!